# What happens when I modify the source code of a running python program?

Tags: python, interpreter

## file_a.py

```
while 1:
    print 1
```

When I remove, rename, even change "print 1" to "print 2",
it is still running with printing 1.

Does it mean python runs with pyc files? What kind of feature of interpreter works here?

Comment: Even if it did use the raw source file, re-reading the file every time a line needed to be executed would be ridiculously slow.

Comment: It reads the file into memory once; it won't keep rereading the file if you change it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand the execution process. With most conventional Python implementations, it essentially goes like this: your source file is compiled into bytecode, and that bytecode is run in a VM. Changing the source file after the fact has no bearing on code that is already running.

What you describe *is* a feature of some languages, however (e.g. Erlang). It's called [hot swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping).

Comment: I've heard that it can be a problem in bash, and that to avoid it you can wrap your code in braces to force bash to read it all before running it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so if i have a long-time python program, when i run it, there is no influence by editing its source code until i abort and rerun the python program again.